# psycopg2 enum types

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following type in postgres 9.2:

```
CREATE TYPE profile_categories AS ENUM
(
    'particulier',
    'professionel',
    'assureur',
    'manager'
);
```

So I want to register it with :

`psycopg2.extras.register_composite('profile_categories', conn, globally=True)`

but then i got an error :

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: PostgreSQL type 'profile_categories' not found`

All my ENUM TYPEs failed to register properly, whereas other types registers fine such as :

```
CREATE TYPE _result AS
(
    id                  TEXT,
    msg                 TEXT
);
```

How to register ENUM TYPEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is failing because enum is not a **composite** type.  I looked through the docs and I couldn't find anything relating to enum types.  I would probably just treat it as text and trap errors.

It looks like the registration process (from the docs) is used when additional processing might be required so you can process point types, geometric types, tuple types, etc.  ENUM types don't require processing when they are received from the db so this would make sense.

Comment: that is correct, until you use array above the enum. In that case, psycopg2 returns the array as a string literal instead of list of strings. Custom type casting must be used in that case: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#database-types-casting-functions